# How does one calculate how big something has to be, to be seen at a given distance?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, optics, geometry, vision, distance

Ignoring curvature of the Earth.

How do I calculate the size an object would need to be in order to appear to be approx 1cm tall at a given distance?

Comment: Use similar triangles.

Comment: the angle subtended  by an object at your eye should be same for objects at various distances which may differ in size - so if you see an object of size one cm. at least distance of distinct vision say 25 cm - so you can calculate the size at given position.

Comment: There are visual clues that let a person know that they are looking at something from a distance, other than size such as fog and how it moves when you move.  Take that in mind as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $w$ be the actual size of the object, $d$ be the distance to the object, $w_r$ be the size of a reference object, and $d_r$ be the distance to the reference object.

If you want your object to appear to be the same size at some distance $d$ as a reference object at a reference distance $d_r$, then using the properties of similar triangles...

[image: similar triangles diagram]

$$\frac{w}{d} = \frac{w_r}{d_r}$$

Solving for $w$, the size of your object,

$$w = w_r \frac{d}{d_r}$$

For example, if you want an object at 20 meters to appear to be the same size as a 1 cm object at 3 meters, you would plug in like so:

$$w = 0.01 ~\rm{m} \frac{20 ~\rm m}{3 ~\rm m} = 0.067 ~\rm{m} = 6.7 ~\rm{cm}$$